# How to find missing number from output in Ansible

Tags: ansible

My playlist has below contains

```
- set_fact:
    missnu={{out.stdout_lines}}
  register: missnu

- debug: msg={{missnu}}
```

And I am getting below output,

```
TASK [debug] **********************
ok: [192.168.0.10] => {
"msg": [
    "1 2 3 4"
]
}
```

This is expected result, however I want to find the number which is missing from this.
Meaning if the result is `"1 2 4"` OR `"2 3 4"` OR `"2 4"` how would I get those missing numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code (it's a simple python code), It worked for me. In below 6 is the limit which I have set to test you can change it as per your requirement.
So by this the numbers which you get from `out.stdout.lines` will get removed from limit which you set (6 or any number which you want) and remaining numbers will show.

```
- name: Getting Missing Numbers
   shell: python -c "ma = {{ out.stdout_lines }}; num = [int(i) for i in ma[0].split()]; mn = list(set(range(1, 6 + 1)) - set(num)); print(mn)"
  register: mynu

- debug: msg={{mynu.stdout}}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the stdout from some command but I'll assume you know the expected result and have that stored in a variable somewhere.  For this I'd use the `difference` filter.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    sample_out_ml: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
    sample_out_sl: "1 2 3 4"
    expected: [ 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ]
  tasks:

  - name: Show difference when cmd outputs multi-line
    debug:
      msg: "{{ expected | difference(sample_out_ml) }}"

  - name: Show difference when cmd outputs on single line
    debug:
      msg: "{{ expected | difference(sample_out_sl.split(' ') | map('int') ) }}"
```

EDIT Based on your comments I provided a more robust example of how you might do this.  If you're going all in on Ansible you should try and refrain from using the `command` modules.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It prints `"msg": "Hello world!"` not the missing numbers

Comment: I may have missed a quote or two.  I updated my answer .  What version of Ansible are you running?

Comment: To Test this I have added `allnu: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]` so the missing number should be `5` instead it shows `"msg": [
        1, 
        2, 
        3, 
        4, 
        5
    ]
` Ansible version is `2.7.0`

Comment: It will not work, To verify this I have tried this `msg: "{{ allnu | difference([1, 2, 3, 4]) }}"` And I get exact missing number i.e `5`. However my output like `"1 2 3 4"
` it's not a list to work with your way.